# php variables set but cannot be accessed: Notice : Undefined index:

Tags: php, session-variables

I've set my session data and it seems to be set as `var_dump($_SESSION["favfilms"]["title"])` suggests returning me a massive string with all the correct session data. However when I go to output the data by specifying `echo $_SESSION["favfilms"]["title"]` I get an error for an Undefined index?

Here's the code for setting the session variables

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
$category = $_POST["category"];

$_SESSION["fav$category"]["title"] = $_POST["title"];
$_SESSION["fav$category"]["body"] = $_POST["body"];
$_SESSION["fav$category"]["img"] = $_POST["img"];
$_SESSION["fav$category"]["category"] = $_POST["category"];
$_SESSION["fav$category"]["id"] = $_POST["id"];   

?>
```

Here is the code where I go to render the data to the view

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
//prints all the session data in one long array structured string
if(isset($_SESSION["favfilms"])){
  echo $_SESSION["favfilms"]["title"] ."<br>";
  echo $_SESSION["favfilms"]["body"]."<br>";
  echo $_SESSION["favfilms"]["img"]."<br>";
  echo $_SESSION["favfilms"]["category"]."<br>";
}else{
  echo "Session fav not set";
  echo $_SESSION["favfilms"]["title"];
}
```

How do I go accessing my session data?

Here is the String it returns me with all my session data

```
array(3) { 
        ["username"]=> string(4) "mfal" 
        ["password"]=> string(3) "pwd" 
        ["favfilms "] => array(5) { 
                    ["title"]=> string(10) "Epic Film!" 
                    ["body"]=> string(449) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat merpproident, merpproidentmerpproident merpproident mollit anim id est laborum." 
                    ["img"]=> string(49) "http://localhost:4000/reviews.com/img/entebbe.jpg" 
                    ["category"]=> string(6) "films " 
                    ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
                    } 
        }
```

Session fav not set

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Also please show us ALL the error message. Dont summarise as it just obfiscates

Comment: `Notice
: Undefined index: favfilms in
F:\4122COMP\web-root\reviews.com\profile.php
on line
144`

Comment: My first guess would be that `$category` does not equal `films`

Comment: It does though read the lengthy string I provided

Comment: Ahh yes, maybe you should read that lengthy string as well. `"favfilms"` !== `"favfilms "`

Comment: No need for that, cheers

Comment: Well to be fair it took me 20 seconds to spot that and 15 of those was me making the sploge readable

Comment: Give yourself a pat on the back